# Identify the movie that the rain scene in Cable Guy mimics?

Tags: cable-guy

The rain scene in Cable Guy seemed to be based of a scene from a classic movie, can anyone identify the original movie?

Comment: Can you give a description of the `rain scene`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably [Singin' in the Rain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045152/) which hass the most parodied movie scene ever with Gene Kelly dancing in a rain soaked street singing the title song.